# mysql - changing table engine from innoDB to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I'm implementing app that requires search feature(full text Search).

EDIT:

I'm using mysql frequent select,insert,update,delete functions, joins also.
I read this [post](http://developer99.blogspot.in/2011/07/mysql-innodb-vs-myisam.html). 
Is there any problem or disadvantages  if i change table engine to MyISAM

Comment: If you use transactions, I'd consider it a downside that MyISAM does not support transactions at all.

Comment: Thanks for reply @joachim. Is there any way to use full text Search with InnoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyISAM does not have transaction support, so if you're using transactions, a conversion to MyISAM will cause problems.

Your best option is probably to use [MySQL 5.6 or higher](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) which supports full text indexes using InnoDB. Earlier versions only support full text indexes on MyISAM tables.

> Full-text indexes can be used only with InnoDB or MyISAM tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.

Comment: @bsg No? `MySQL Community Server
(Current Generally Available Release: 5.6.11)`, also Oracle's fully supported enterprise edition seems to be 5.6.

Comment: 5.6 is the shipping version. It's quite stable now. 5.7 isn't ready yet but will be soon. Don't ever use MyISAM if you can possibly avoid it.